# How to use ChromaKey and Sepia filter with GPUImage at the same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm using for the first time the GPUImage framework of Brad Larson.

I don't know if it's possible, but I would like to use the **GPUImageChromaKeyFilter** and **GPUImageSepiaFilter**. I can use them separately, but at the same time, it doesn't work.
The sepia tone works, but the chromaKey seems doesn't work.

**EDIT 2: WORKING**
Here is my code:

```
- (void)setupCameraAndFilters:(AVCaptureDevicePosition)cameraPostion {

    videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:cameraPostion];
    videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

    // ChromaKey
    chromaKeyFilter = [[GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter alloc] init];
    [(GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter *)chromaKeyFilter setColorToReplaceRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0];

    [videoCamera addTarget:chromaKeyFilter];

    // Input image (replace the green background)
    UIImage *inputImage;
    inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chromaBackground.jpg"];
    sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
    [sourcePicture processImage];
    [sourcePicture addTarget:chromaKeyFilter];

    // Sepia filter
    sepiaFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
    [chromaKeyFilter addTarget:sepiaFilter];

    [sepiaFilter addTarget:self.filteredVideoView];

    [videoCamera startCameraCapture];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the above code doesn't really make sense. In the first example, you have your still image going into the single-input GPUImageChromaKeyFilter, then you try to target both that source image and your video feed to the single-input GPUImageSepiaFilter. One of those two inputs will be overridden by the other.

GPUImageFilterGroups are merely convenience classes for grouping sequences of filters together an an easy-to-reuse package, and won't solve anything here.

If you're trying to blend video with a chroma-keyed image, you need to use a GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter, which takes two inputs and blends them together based on the keying. You can then send that single output image to the sepia tone filter, or however you want to sequence that.

Comment: Thank for your explanation! So, I can achieve this using GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter, GPUImageSepiaFilter and GPUImageFilterGroup ?

Comment: @Lapinou - The GPUImageFilterGroup is unnecessary, as I explain above. If you wish to mix two input sources (like you do here), you need a blend at some point. A GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter will take care of that for you if you direct the two inputs to that.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will try and let you know if I can achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry, but I can't achieve this. I've update my code in my post. It works fine with the GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter, but I really don't know how to add the GPUImageSepiaFilter at the same time.  To be sure I've been clear: I would like to film a green background with a sepia tone, and the green background is replaced with the input image. (Here: chromaBackground.jpg). Thank you so much.

Comment: Well! I finally find the solution. I've update my code. I don't know if it's the right way, but it works. Thank you for your suggestions if needed ;)

Comment: @Lapinou - The above looks fine to me. You feed both video and image into the chroma key blend, which replaces the area in green (or whatever color) within the video with the image. You then take the output of that and apply a sepia tone filter to that. Seems reasonably constructed.

Comment: thank you for your help and good explanation. Thank you also for this beautiful framework!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `GPUImageFilterGroup` filter in order to accomplish what you want. In the examples of the `GPUImage` you can find how to achieve this. Good Luck!

Comment: Yes, I already tried the example. I can achieve this using almost all filters, but not with GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter or GPUImageChromaKeyFilter. I don't understand why.

Comment: Then, wait for the Brad to answer, or, open an issue on GPUImage on github.